# Redirecting all https outgoing requests through proxy from Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, http, networking, proxy, server

I have windows server 2012 with all Internet outgoing traffic blocked. I have an application that needs to access a public web service through https. In our company we use IE proxy for http or https web requests via IE browser. Do you know how to use this proxy to allow the application sends https requests to this external Web Service?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not your application uses the system proxy settings (the ones IE uses and any other WinInet-based application uses) will depend on that application.

What is the application?